# Why would I get this error when building the XML document in vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm trying to build a web service and it should build a new XML out of an existing XML.

the code as follows:

```vb
   <WebMethod(CacheDuration:=0, Description:="GroveHallFromRss")> _
    Public Function GroveHallFromRss() As XmlDocument
        Dim webClient As System.Net.WebClient = New System.Net.WebClient()
        Dim ourUrl As String = "http://123.example.org/RSSSyndicator.aspx?type=N&range=currentyear&expire=Y&location=2-7-165&rssid=18"

    Dim stream AS Stream
    stream = webClient.OpenRead(ourUrl)
    Dim xmlDocument AS XmlDocument = new XmlDocument()
        xmlDocument.Load(stream)


        Dim myXml As XmlDocument = new XmlDocument()
        Using writer As XmlWriter = myXml.CreateNavigator().AppendChild()
            writer.WriteStartDocument()
            writer.WriteStartElement("document")
            For Each item As System.Xml.XmlElement In xmlDocument.Item("item")
                writer.WriteStartElement("event")
                writer.WriteElementString("title", item.Item("title").Value)
                writer.WriteElementString("link", item.Item("link").Value)
                writer.WriteElementString("description", item.Item("description").Value)
                writer.WriteEndElement()
            Next
            writer.WriteEndElement()
            writer.WriteEndDocument()
        End Using

        Return myXml
```

It gives me an error like this:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.    at Portal.GroveHallFromRss()

The problem seem to be around the line of:

> For Each item As System.Xml.XmlElement In xmlDocument.Item("item")

But I'm not sure what caused this. Thanks!

Here goes the XML:

```
<rss version="2.0">
-
<channel>
-
<title>
title 123
</title>
<cf:treatAs>list</cf:treatAs>
<link>http://123/default.aspx</link>
<description>RSS Feed 123 Events Calendar</description>
-
<item>
<title>New 123 (6/18/2012)</title>
-
<link>
http://123.aspx?view=EventDetails&eventidn=9751&information_id=19501&type=&rss=rss
</link>
-
<description>
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td valign="top"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td style="padding-bottom:1px;"><b>Start Date:</b>&nbsp;</td><td style="padding-bottom:1px;">6/18/2012</td><td>&nbsp;<b>Start Time:</b>&nbsp;</td><td>8:00 AM</td></tr><tr><td><b>End Date:</b>&nbsp;</td><td>6/18/2012</td><td>&nbsp;<b>End Time:</b>&nbsp;</td><td>4:00 PM</td></tr></table><br />123<br />Room: 123<br /><br />nil</td></tr></table>
</description>
<pubDate>Mon, 18 Jun 2012 12:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
<category>06/18/2012</category>
</item>
+
<item>
<title>123 Orientation (6/19/2012)</title>
-
<link>
http://123/EventList.aspx?view=EventDetails&eventidn=9770&information_id=19539&type=&rss=rss
</link>
-
<description>
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td valign="top"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td style="padding-bottom:1px;"><b>Start Date:</b>&nbsp;</td><td style="padding-bottom:1px;">6/19/2012</td><td>&nbsp;<b>Start Time:</b>&nbsp;</td><td>8:00 AM</td></tr><tr><td><b>End Date:</b>&nbsp;</td><td>6/19/2012</td><td>&nbsp;<b>End Time:</b>&nbsp;</td><td>4:00 PM</td></tr></table><br />123<br />Room: 106<br /><br />nil</td></tr></table>
</description>
<pubDate>Tue, 19 Jun 2012 12:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
<category>06/19/2012</category>
</item>
-
<item>
<title>123 (6/20/2012)</title>
-
<link>
http://123/EventList.aspx?view=EventDetails&eventidn=9789&information_id=19577&type=&rss=rss
</link>
-
<description>
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td valign="top"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td style="padding-bottom:1px;"><b>Start Date:</b>&nbsp;</td><td style="padding-bottom:1px;">6/20/2012</td><td>&nbsp;<b>Start Time:</b>&nbsp;</td><td>8:00 AM</td></tr><tr><td><b>End Date:</b>&nbsp;</td><td>6/20/2012</td><td>&nbsp;<b>End Time:</b>&nbsp;</td><td>4:00 PM</td></tr></table><br />123 Grove Hall<br />Room: 106<br /><br />nil</td></tr></table>
</description>
<pubDate>Wed, 20 Jun 2012 12:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
<category>06/20/2012</category>
</item>

</channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: Post the XML, it'd help.

Answer (score 1):

**The xml as posted is not well-formed.**

Specifically, some of the `link` elements include an invalid character. Valid Xml only allows the ampersand character (`&`) as part of an xml entity, and so you must encode the url in the link element so that the url's query parameters look like this (as an example):

> &amp;eventidn=9770

instead of:

> &eventidn=9770

Xml parsing rules *require* xml parsers to treat well-formedness errors as fatal, and so your XmlDocument object has to throw an exception and cannot continue to finish the document.

Reading other answers, it looks like you haven't got as far as reading any link elements yet, so you likely have another issue as well, but mark my words: fix that other issue, and this one is waiting for you. If you're really lucky, the xml is encoded correctly and this is just an effect of whatever tool you use to view it, but this is something that's always worth checking for.

Comment: Explains why I had to remove those to get it to load. I assumed the xml was valid. You know what they say about assumptions...

Answer (score 0):

If it' failing on that line, then most likely `xmlDocument.Item("item")` is null.

You're at the wrong node level. You are searching for "item" further up the tree than it is. You need to get the node that item is attached to to access it through Item(). You may be able to use a path, such as "rss/channel/item". Not exactly sure of that syntax. But that's your problem, you are searching for item at the document level instead of at the node level it's attached to. It's like trying to get somewhere 3 turns away in one turn.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: I loaded your xml into an XMLDocument and grabbed item like this:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim xdoc As XmlDocument

    xdoc = New XmlDocument()
    xdoc.Load(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) & "\test.xml")

    For Each e As XmlElement In xdoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("channel")
        If e.Name = "item" Then
            MsgBox("I am an item")
        End If
    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: I could confirm it's that line, but as you could see in the XML, the item does exist. Not sure why it's still complaining

Comment: I kind realized that later on and tried xmlDocument.Item("rss").Item("channel").Item("item") and still no luck. Thanks for your quick reply though...

Comment: Have you tried XMLDocument.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Channel").SelectSingleNode("Item") to get to that node? I still think that's the problem and we're not just grabbing it correctly.

Comment: A quick update is that I have managed to partially get it working, by using "xmlDocument.Item("rss").Item("channel").Item("item")", I get five items, (still not all). and it now fails on "item.Item("title").Value"

Comment: I had to remove a few lines of your xml as it was not saving correctly from notepad for some reason. It was complaining on the hyperlinks and the table node.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the nodes you are iterating in `foreach` could be other stuff than elements (like white space and other). As a human, you see just elements but not the other "technical" nodes in document.

Just check that `item` is not `null` and do rest of the loop normally.

Note: `item As System.Xml.XmlElement` does not mean that you will get only `XmlElement`-s in your loop but that runtime will try to cast current xml node to `XmlElement`. If the result of such casting is `null`, that means that current node is not an `XmlElement` and should be skipped in processing.

Comment: Thanks for your help. A quick update is that I have managed to partially get it working, by using "xmlDocument.Item("rss").Item("channel").Item("item")", I get  five items, (still not all). and it now fails on "item.Item("title").Value"

Comment: I just mentioned that in my comments below. =)